# Find total number of permutation of sub-categories ignoring reflections

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I have Categories and total number of elements in each category.

> 

```
for example :   
  2   L,    
  2   S, and   
  1   P
```

I could line them up in the following 16 ways.

```
llpss
llsps
llssp
lplss
lpsls
lslps
lslsp
lspls
lspsl
lsslp
lsspl
pllss
sllps
sllsp
slpls
slslp
```

> Before you object that the list is incomplete, you should know that
>   mirror images are considered  to be equivalent.
>
> For example, since "sspll" is the same as "llpss" from back to front,
>   we counts them as one.
>
> You are given a int[] containing the number of element of each
>   category(L,S,P,A,B). Return an int stating the number of ways they can
>   be lined up, ignoring reflections.

```
for example :
 {2, 2, 1}

Returns: 16         // illustrated above.   

{2, 2, 2}

Returns: 48
```

> What I can think of about the algorithm is very basic :
>
> - Convert the number to their respective alphabets(L,S,P,A,B ; B at    index 0).
> - Count the total permutation possible with those alphabets
> - remove the reflections
>
>   But this is certainly not optimal solution.Can anyone tell me any other solution for this problem.
>     Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by "Convert the number to their respective alphabets(L,S,P,A,B ; B at index 0)."?  Where did B and A come from?

Comment: It means as we provide  {2,2,1} as input we will change it to 1 B, 2 A, and 2 P i.e {PPAAB}.I hope I made it clear..

Comment: So what about L and S?

Comment: It is not provide during input so we will take them as 0.

Comment: There are mathematical approaches to this, usually explained in connection with working out how many different necklaces you can make with coloured beads. Links include http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma and http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2012/Huisinga.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the number of words of type (*a*,*b*,*c*) discounting reflections is:

```
[ (a+b+c)! / a! / b! / c! + correction ] / 2
```

where *correction* is the number of words whose reflection equals themselves.

For example, for (2,2,1) the correction term is 2 for the two words `lspsl` and `slpls`.
The total number of words is (5! / 2! / 2! + 2)/2 = (120/4 + 2) / 2 = 32/2 = 16.

For (1,1,1) the correction term is 0. The correction term is also 0 for (2,1,1). The correction term can be computed directly from the numbers *a*, *b* and *c* (left as an exercise.)

Comment: For any word w,  the set { w, reflect(w) } consists of two elements except for the words where w = reflect(w), so imagine the set of all words as a union of a bunch of pairs + some singletons. The number of singletons is the correction term. Each pair only counts 1 towards the answer; then do a little algebra.

Comment: Sorry I'm really not getting the point. Can you post some of the links from where you have reference..

Comment: how can we compute correction term from a,b,c? I am trying to understand it but no success..

Comment: Re the correction term... Suppose you have (10,12,1). The third letter must go in the middle. Then you have 5 _a_'s and 6 _b_'s you can put on the left side in any order and this determines the entire word.

Comment: It would be nice if you show it with example.Visualizing something you are not clear is difficult..Hope you agree..